# PHP PDO login Username and Password not found

Tags: php, pdo

So i followed a tutorial that shows how to login,

But i made a username and password in my phpmyadmin, But everytime when i try to login it says: Username or Password not found this is the code;

```
    <!--Begin webshop WOOOH-->

<?php


session_start();

    //DB configuration Constants
    include("class.php");
    //PDO Database Connection
    try {
        $databaseConnection = new PDO('mysql:host='._HOST_NAME_.';dbname='._DATABASE_NAME_, _USER_NAME_, _DB_PASSWORD);
        $databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $errMsg = '';
        //username and password sent from Form
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        if($username == '')
            $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Username<br>';

        if($password == '')
            $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Password<br>';


        if($errMsg == ''){
            $records = $databaseConnection->prepare('SELECT id,username,password FROM  tbl_users WHERE username = :username');
            $records->bindParam(':username', $username);
            $records->execute();
            $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($password, $results['password'])){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $results['username'];
                header('location:dashboard.php');
                exit;
            }else{
                $errMsg .= 'Username and Password are not found<br>';
            }
        }
    }

?>

<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">

    <title>Webshop 2016</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Webshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--Main content!-->
        <div id="content">

<div align="center">
        <div style="width:300px; border: solid 1px #006D9C; " align="left">
            <?php
                if(isset($errMsg)){
                    echo '<div style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:12px;">'.$errMsg.'</div>';
                }
            ?>
            <div style="background-color:#006D9C; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>
            <div style="margin:30px">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <label>Username  :</label><input type="text" name="username" class="box"/><br /><br />
                    <label>Password  :</label><input type="password" name="password" class="box" /><br/><br />
                    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit" class='submit'/><br />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the class.php (the connection file)

```
    <?php
define('_HOST_NAME_', 'localhost');
define('_USER_NAME_', 'root');
define('_DB_PASSWORD', '####');
define('_DATABASE_NAME_', 'ws_webshop');

//PDO Database Connection
try {
 $databaseConnection = new PDO('mysql:host='._HOST_NAME_.';dbname='._DATABASE_NAME_, _USER_NAME_, _DB_PASSWORD);
 $databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Does anyone see the problem?

the user and pass is demo / demo but he says theres no Username or password found...

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Did you use `password_hash()` to put the password in the database? If not, `password_verify()` will not work.

Comment: I put them in as plain text, ill try to change it too hash

Comment: You need to put the return hash value of `password_hash` into the database field.

Comment: How can i check for it with plain text? Because i have no idea why the guy in the tutorial didnt make it for MD5,

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) because they are insecure @LucStey

Comment: @JayBlanchard i followed the tutorial haha

Comment: @JayBlanchard my fault, I saw the count($results) before and thought it have the user there. I've remove my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php):

> Returns TRUE if the password and hash match, or FALSE otherwise.

If you did not use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to insert the password in the database your check using [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)  attempt here:

```
if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($password, $results['password'])){
```

will always fail because the function expects a plain password to compare against the hashed value of the password. for more insight on PHP's password functions read [this post.](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)

---

In addition you may find yourself wanting to limit passwords and [you really shouldn't do that](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html).

---

[image]

Comment: Im manually putting in the passwords to the database, because i dont have a register form yet, i tried to translate to Hash and put it in but same result, no username or password

Comment: Then you cannot verify the password with that function @LucStey. Make sure that your database column for the hashes is large enough too. I typically set the column type to `text`.

Comment: Well, i did this just to get the has: echo password_hash("demo", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n"; so i get the hash for a sec that works :D, so when i make the register i make sure to use password_hash, thanks!

Comment: Yes it did @JayBlanchard

Comment: Awesome @LucStey! Glad I could help!